# Cocoapods 0.35 is failing build

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, clang, cocoapods

I'm working on a Swift app in Xcode 6. Everything was working okay until I decided to install cocoa pods and a pod. When I try to run it on the simulator, I get the following error:

```
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Before the error, there is a listing of all those duplicate symbols.

First few lines in error message:

```
Ld /<...>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<...>-gydnbbvfswpkkodlsuxdkpzkklzb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<...>.app/<...> normal x86_64
cd "/<...>/Documents/iOS Apps/<...>/<...>"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
```

I even tried uninstalling the pod, but the error persists. I'm completely stuck – any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you opening the .xcworkspace file, and not the .xcodeproj? when you run `pod install` do you see any error messages? What pod are you trying to install?

Comment: @cmyr Yes, I'm opening the workspace file. I'm trying to install https://github.com/jaredsinclair/JTSImageViewController and I see no error messages before building. All methods etc are available for code completion, and I did so by importing the header file in my bridging header file for Swift

Comment: @cmyr I have a target called appname and another one called appnameTests

Comment: @cmyr I don't think its included, but just to be sure – how do I verify whether I have it included?

Comment: actually ignore that comment. Is it possible this is a duplicate of [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1729)?

Comment: Here is what my project looks like: https://copy.com/VEhRRG6N7z42kIPQ I'm new to this stuff, but this looks not right Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should update your CocoaPods to 0.36 or a later version, and add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile. See this: [CocoaPods 0.36 - Framework and Swift Support](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

- You have put the same class implementation into two different files;
- You actually have just one implementation of this class, however you are also linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.